# Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by null

Tags: reactjs

The function is called on form submission. at first, it is working as expected but when calling this function on form submit. I get this following error.index.js:1 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by null. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks:

### Previous render            Next render

1. useState                   useState
2. undefined                  useState

Here is the code sample :

```
function TablerowsAdd (  x,i,header,handleRemove, startEditing,editIdx,handleChange,stopEditing,handleRemoveField,fieldIdx,startEditingField,fieldheader) {
    
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    

    const currentlyEditing = editIdx === i;  
    
   
    return (
        <React.Fragment key={`tr-${i}`}>
        <TableRow key={`tr-${i}`}>           
            {header.map((y, k) => (
                <TableCell key={`trc-${k}`}>
                    {currentlyEditing ? (
                        <TextField
                            name={y.prop}
                            onChange={e => handleChange(e, y.prop, i)}
                            value={x[y.prop]}
                        />
                    ) : (
                            x[y.prop]
                        )}
                </TableCell>
            ))}
            <TableCell>                
                {currentlyEditing ? (
                    <CheckIcon onClick={() => stopEditing()} />
                ) : (
                        <EditIcon onClick={() => startEditing(i)} />
                    )}
                <DeleteIcon onClick={() => handleRemove(i)} />
                <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}  >
                        {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
                    </IconButton>
            </TableCell>        
        </TableRow>
        
         <TableRow>
         <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
           <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
             <Box margin={1}>
               <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                 Fields
               </Typography>
               <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                 <TableHead>

                 <TableRow>
                        {fieldheader.map((x, i) => (
                            <TableCell key={`thc-${i}`}>{x.name}  </TableCell>
                        ))}
                      
                    </TableRow>
                 </TableHead>
                 <TableBody>
                     
                   {x.fields.map((fieldRow,y) => (
                     <TableRow key={`tr-${y}`}>
                       <TableCell>{fieldRow.bitname}</TableCell>
                         
                       
                       <TableCell>{fieldRow.bitmask}</TableCell>
                       <TableCell >{fieldRow.bitvalue}</TableCell>
                       <TableCell >{fieldRow.maskname}</TableCell>
                       <TableCell > {fieldRow.doc} </TableCell>
                       <TableCell > 
                     
                        <DeleteIcon    onClick={() => handleRemoveField(i,fieldRow.bitname,y)} /> </TableCell>              

                     </TableRow>
                   ))}
                   
                 </TableBody>
               </Table>
             </Box>
           </Collapse>
         </TableCell>
       </TableRow>
       </React.Fragment>
    ); };
```

Comment: did you gind a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

If call count of `TablerowsAdd` varies, the call count of `useState` varies too.
Try using a component: `<TablerowsAdd/>` instead of method call: `TablerowsAdd()`. This way `useState` is called exactly once per component